# DBSCAN not giving correct results on spatial transportation data

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, spatial, dbscan, transport

I am trying to form clusters in the transportation data involving lat and long but

I am getting incorrect results as it is classifying points even having moderate

distances between them in the same cluster.

slat - source latitudes

slong - source longitudes

```
    coords = source.as_matrix(columns=['slat', 'slong'])

    kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
epsilon = 2 / kms_per_radian
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=3, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords))

cluster_labels = db.labels_
source['cluster'] = db.labels_ # source is  the dataset
```

I tried plotting all the points in cartoDB and clusters were not proper,

As locations having more distances than 2 km were in the same clusters.

please anyone could tell how to do it better

I followed steps from  [clustering spatial data](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/)

I have not followed the steps for cluster centre point as I could not import the necessary library in python .

Is that the reason  why I am not correct results.

Please tell about it.

In short My aim to replicate this  for latitudes and longitudes for source and destination  as Grab did it in the article with the image  shown as

[image]

Article link -

[Grab clustering rides](https://engineering.grab.com/the-data-and-science-behind-grabshare-part-i#10)

please offer any insight on  how to replicate it

Comment: Hi Jatin, did you figure it out? I too am working with spatial data.

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN explicitly *allows* points to have distances larger than epsilon as long as they are **density connected**. That is why it is called a *density* based approach, and why you can get clusters of arbitrary shape.

It is a frequent misconception that any two points of a cluster would be at most epsilon apart. That is called complete-linkage and will give approximately spherical clusters.

Comment: @ Anony-Mousse can you suggest an way to produce the desired  output so that it clusters accordingly.

Comment: You didn't tell what the desired output is. And I suggested an alternative approach in my answer already.